# How to map each value in data frame to 0 or 1

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R consisting of non-negative integers. I'd like to convert each value in the data frame to either 0 or 1 such that: `x => x > 0 ? 1 : 0`

I've come across the `apply()` method, but this seems to take the entire row/col as input. Is there a method for mapping each individual data point to a new value?

Comment: `df[] <- as.numeric(df > 0)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, R doesn't have a ternary operator, gotta just do `as.integer(x > 0)` (since TRUE/FALSE gets coerced to 1/0).

Comment: @Psidom @Frank Thanks! I'm new to R, could you explain why one has to use `df[]` instead of just `df` on the LHS? Also, what is the difference between `as.numeric()` and `as.integer()`?

Comment: Because `as.numeric()` or `as.integer()` will flatten out the original data frame, using `df[]` can maintain the original shape of the data frame while only change the data inside. The difference between `as.integer()` and `as.numeric` is that the former coerce the logical to integer while the latter coerce it to numeric(double type internally).

Comment: You can even do `+(df > 0)`; but this isn't quite as readable as using `as.numeric`/`as.integer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ifelse similar to a ternary operator .

Here is an example :

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,0)
x <- ifelse(x > 0 , 1 , 0)
x
[1] 1 1 1 1 0
```

Another example , for a data frame :

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(0,0,0,1,2,3), B=c(0,10,20,30,40,0))
> df
  A  B
1 0  0
2 0 10
3 0 20
4 1 30
5 2 40
6 3  0

modified_df <- data.frame(A = ifelse(df$A > 0 , 1 , 0 ) , B = ifelse(df$B > 0 , 1 , 0 ))

> modified_df
  A B
1 0 0
2 0 1
3 0 1
4 1 1
5 1 1
6 1 0
```